Как удалить Kotlin из проекта? Android studio
Случайно добавил activity с языком Kotlin, теперь проект стал весить в 2 раза больше. Как его удалить полностью?
Пробовал сделать так но не получилось, возможно информация устарела
Пробовал добавить в свой build.gradle.kts это, но проект вообще перестал запускаться:
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isShrinkResources = true
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
}


Что именно не получилось? Вы любую активити добавите и Котлин там будет, пусть и неявно. AndroidX весь на Котлин. Удалите упоминания "kotlin" из своих .gradle файлов, это максимум что вы можете сделать.

@EugeneKrivenja я так и сделал, но размер приложения то не уменьшился

Создайте новый проект и перенесите туда исходники и ресурсы если сомневаетесь.

У Gradle есть полезная команда dependencies, поможет определить кто и что в проект тянет: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html

@EugeneKrivenja можете написать пример использования в ответах?

Мне помогло решение из этого ресурса
А конкретно:
buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = true
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }

        debug {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = true
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }

Добавление этого кода в build.gradle.kts (Module:app)

Kotlin уже стал частью системы разработки и стандартных библиотек для Android и избавиться от него вам вряд ли удастся.
У Gradle есть полезная команда для вывода дерева зависимостей для любого модуля в проекте. Пример вызова для модуля app
./gradlew app:dependencies

в его ответе можно найти такие примеры
+--- androidx.databinding:viewbinding:8.5.2  
|    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.8.1  
|         \--- androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.8.1  
|              \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.7.10 -> 2.0.0

либо
+--- com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.22
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22 -> 2.0.0 (c)

либо
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.11.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.9 -> 5.0.0-alpha.14
|         +--- com.squareup.okio:okio:3.9.0
|         |    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio-jvm:3.9.0
|         |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.21 -> 2.0.0 (*)

либо
+--- com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:6.15.2
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.22 (*)

либо
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:5.0.0-alpha.14
|    +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.14 (*)
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.23 -> 2.0.0 (*)

Т.е. куда не ткни, везде Котлин. И что-то делать с этим уже бесполезно в наше время. Примеры взяты из реального проекта.
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html

то есть уменьшить размер уже никак не получиться??

@clay, получится, когда научитесь использовать обфускатор: https://developer.android.com/build/shrink-code

@woesss добавил в вопрос, посмотрите

Вопрос потерял логику. Котлин и code shrink совершенно параллельные вещи.

@EugeneKrivenja, из первого же предложения понятно что автор таким способом хотел уменьшить размер приложения. Это изначально "проблема XY"
